# Default parameter as generic type

Tags: swift, generics, default

I have protocol and his implementation written in Swift:

```
protocol P {
}

struct A: P {
}
```

Protocol is used as generic type for some function:

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T) {
}

func foo() {
    foo(param: A())
}
```

Until now everything works properly. But I would like to set A() as a default parameter of given function:

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T = A()) {
}
```

Unfortunately with following error:

> Default argument value of type 'A' cannot be converted to type 'T'.

Or

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T = A() as P) {
}
```

,

```
let a: P = A()
func foo<T: P>(param: T = a) {
}
```

Returns:

> Default argument value of type 'P' cannot be converted to type 'T'

Or

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T = A() as T) {
}
```

Returns:

> 'A' is not convertible to 'T'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

What I'm doing wrong? Where is the problem?

I do not want to use force cast like this:

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T = A() as! T) {
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to enforce a non-generic default argument in a generic function: you should probably think over what you're trying to achieve here.

For the sake of the discussion, you *could* include an attempted cast of `A()` to `T` in your function signature, but you'd need to change the argument type to optional to allow failed conversion (`nil`), e.g.

```
func foo<T: P>(param: T? = (A() as? T)) { }
```

A more sound alternative is including - in addition to your generic function - a concrete non-generic function for instances where `T` is `A` (concrete functions will take precedence over generic ones), in which case you can include the default argument of `A()` in the function signature of the concrete function. E.g.

```
protocol P { }
struct A: P { }
extension Int: P { }

func foo<T: P>(param: T) { print("called generic foo") }
func foo(param: A = A()) { print("called A specific foo") }

foo()    // called A specific foo (making use of default arg)
foo(A()) // called A specific foo
foo(1)   // called generic foo
```

Note that the non-generic `foo` is called even though `A` conforms to `P` (`A` *could've* made use of the generic `foo`): there's no conflict here as the concrete function takes precedence.

---

If you, on the other hand, just want your generic function to allow calling without the single argument (i.e., making use of a default argument), you can include a blueprint of a simple initializer in `P`, allowing you to initialize an instance of the generic type as default argument; see [@Sulthan:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327170/4573247).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is to add a requirement for an initializer to the protocol:

```
protocol P {
    init()
}

struct A: P {
    var x: Int

    init() {
        x = 10
    }
}

func foo<T: P>(param param: T = T()) {
}
```

However, you will have another problem. The type of the passed parameter decides the type of the generic so you will have to specify the generic type somehow else.