# Is it possible to provide a default value for a template function argument?

Tags: ios, swift, templates, generics, default-value

Consider the following code:

```
protocol Foo {
    func f() -> Void
}

class Bar1: Foo {
    func f() {
        print("Bar1 f")
    }
}

class Bar2: Foo {
    func f() {
        print("Bar2 f")
    }
}

func function<T:Foo>(arg:T = Bar2()) {
    arg.f()
}
```

It gives an error `Value of type Bar2 cannot be converted to type T`, which seems to be pure nonsense, because `T` is guaranteed to be compatible with `Foo` and this is the context within which the assignment should operate.
To prove it:

```
let global: Foo = Bar2()
global.f()
```

This works just fine.

I am wondering why such a discrepancy exists and if there is any workaround for it?

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327164/3397793

Comment: @MuhammadHassan This basically answers my question for a workaround. The curious thing is why Apple lets such a situation exist.

Comment: That sorta makes two of us.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `Bar2()` as Generic type `T`

```
func function<T:Foo>(arg:T = Bar2() as! T) {
        arg.f()
}
```