# How to use generic default parameters

Tags: swift, parameters, rawrepresentable

This is my code:

```
class Person {
    init<T: RawRepresentable>(raw: T = Child.johnDoe) {}
}

enum Child: String {
    case johnDoe
}
```

It doesn't compile. The error is:

> Default argument value of type 'Child' cannot be converted to type 'T'

Why can't it be converted? According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable), `Child.someEnum` is `RawRepresentable`:

> Enumerations with Raw Values For any enumeration with a string,
>   integer, or floating-point raw type, the Swift compiler automatically
>   adds RawRepresentable conformance. When defining your own custom
>   enumeration, you give it a raw type by specifying the raw type as the
>   first item in the enumeration’s type inheritance list.

This also compiles:

```
class Person {
    static func accept<T: RawRepresentable>(raw: T) where T.RawValue == String {}
}

enum Child: String {
    case johnDoe
}

Person.accept(raw: Child.johnDoe)
```

Why doesn't it work as a default parameter?

Use case: I want to accept any `RawPresentable` value, so I can extract the `rawValue` from it. I want to provide a default value (always "") (I just create a struct with `rawValue = ""`). I do not want to create multiple initializers, since I got some subclasses and that would get a mess. The best for me is just to provide a default `RawRepresentable` object.

When I add a cast:
    init(ty: T = (Child.johnDoe as! T)) where T.RawValue == String {

```
}
```

Or make it nillable:

```
(ty: T? = nil)
```

It compiles. But now I can not call:

```
let x = Person()
```

It gives the error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default parameter as generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326992/default-parameter-as-generic-type)

Comment: @DmitriyKirakosyan This question and that question have the same title, but seeing the answers and actual question, I think the content of my question is different :). The answers stated in that question doesn't work for my case.

Comment: What is your use case that the answers in that question don't work for?

Comment: @dan I added the use case. The questions in that answer states I need to add a initializer, but when I do that it still won't work.

Comment: To make it work as you want, you have to add a specific `init`, eg: `init(raw: Child = Child.johnDoe)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible. However, you have to use your own protocol and add the default value to that protocol:

```
protocol MyRawRepresentable: RawRepresentable {
    static var defaultValue: Self { get }
}

class Person {
    init<T: MyRawRepresentable>(raw: T = T.defaultValue) {}
}

enum Child: String, MyRawRepresentable {
    case johnDoe

    static let defaultValue: Child = .johnDoe
}
```

There is another issue though. How will you specify the generic type if you use the default parameter value and all you will have will be just `Person.init()`?

The only solution I see is to also specify a default generic type which means you actually want:

```
class Person {
   init<T: RawRepresentable>(raw: T) {
   }

   convenience init() {
       self.init(raw: Child.johnDoe)
   }
}
```

Unless you actually want to make `Person` itself a generic class because then you could just use

```
Person<Child>.init()
```

Comment: Yes I ran into the problem trying yo contruct a Person without arguments, i editted my question about the compile error I get. I dont really care about the generic type, but Swift wants me somehow to specify a type...